professor not supporting in anyways
I recently graduated with a degree in engineering, and my advisor encouraged me to start my PhD, promising to provide funding for my studies. However, I’m now in my second semester, and my professor has not paid any stipend so far. In addition to my living expenses, I’ve had to cover $15k in registration fees from my own pocket.
I requested a meeting with him, and after several cancellations, we finally met. When I asked about the funding, he said the project is still pending and hasn’t been approved yet. If it does get approved, he will pay me. When I registered last semester, he assured me that he would start paying once I am registered, but now he's saying the project lacks the necessary funds.
One of my fellow researchers had a similar issue, argued with the professor, changed supervisors, and left the group. I’m unsure what to do next. I can’t afford to keep paying tuition and working without any stipend, and with the project lacking support from my professor, I feel like I’m wasting my time without clear direction on what I’m supposed to work on.
earlier I created a post about laptop:
PhD supervisor does not support
it turned out that that was a researchmate laptop since he had a fight with professor, prof took his laptop and passed it to me. Now prof is asking me to do that person's work.
What should I do?

You seem to have faced a very similar problem six years ago. How did you resolve that one? And do you have any idea why these kinds of things keep happening to you?

In any case, this is a duplicate of your question from last month, what was itself closed (for being unclear). The SE model is to add clarification to your old question, not to post a new one.
